# Equals or == throws "Ambiguous reference" Error in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

I user swiftUI on xcode beta 4 and I can't see if objects or properties are equal.
When I want to equate something, I will get on the same line the error: "Ambiguous reference to member '=='".

This is my code, but in other occacions in my code, I can't equate other things like enums either. Is this my mistake or a bug?

```
struct PickerView: View {
    @ObjectBinding var data: Model
    //    let selector: PickerType
    let selector: String

    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if selector == "countdown" {
                Picker(selection: $data.countDownTime, label: Text("select Time")) {
                    ForEach(1...240) { diget in
                        Text("\(diget)")
                    }

                }
                .frame(width: width, height: (height/2), alignment: .center)
            } else {
                Picker(selection: $data.exercise, label: Text("select Time")) {
                    ForEach(data.exercises) { exercise in
                        Text("\(exercise)")
                    }

                }
                .frame(width: width, height: (height/2), alignment: .center)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SwiftUI views, errors may sometimes be misleading. It may appear in one part of the code, but the real cause may be several lines of code up or down.

In your case, you put the wrong view name:

```swift
PickerView(selection: $data.countDownTime, label: Text("select Time"))
```

when you really meant:

```swift
Picker(selection: $data.countDownTime, label: Text("select Time"))
```

and because PickerView actually does exist, but has different parameters, you got a very misleading error.

When something of the sort happens, I recommend you comment the code that gives you an error that makes no sense, and you will see the compiler will point you somewhere else. Hopefully, the right place. In your case, if you temporarily change: `if selector == "countdown"` by `if true`, the compiler would have point you in the right direction. Try it and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Most interestingly, I just checked my code and it doesn't say PickerView, it says Picker. But I used your tip in the end and it now throws the error **Type of expression is ambiguous without more context** at `Text("\(exercise)")`. Thanks for the starter!